# Magento 2.4.5 all URL goees to pub folder

Tags: magento2

I have upgraded my Magento store to 2.4.5 and all links and URL goes or redirect to the pub folder.
Please anyone can help me here?

URL like - https://project.com/pub/dash-board-polishing-450ml.html

Comment: Can you post the error on top or a picture of your details?

Comment: @huanth no error there is URL change with pub folder

Comment: See updated question

Comment: Can you please tell us  that your magento 2.4.5 is running fine or not. I want to use Magento 2.4.5 for my site?